# App authentication failing on mobile devices only

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook app using the PHP SDK. This is all working fine, except that when a user visits it on a mobile device (by visiting `apps.facebook.com/myappname/` using their web browser), the login is getting stuck in an infinite redirect loop (presumably continually redirecting them back to the Facebook login page).

The login code is pretty standard:

```
$userID = $facebook->getUser();
if ($userID) {
    [store stuff in session]

} else {
    [Javascript redirect to $facebook->getLoginUrl()]
}
```

this was working before but must have been broken with one of Facebook's recent changes.

Comment: Have you tried changing the user agent to test your theory and confirming the headers sent and received?

Comment: If I use a mobile user agent I can repeat the problem. Facebook correctly redirects back with the code param in the query string, but the getUser() call is returning null with this present, so the login part is failing. Still works fine for desktops though.

Comment: Managed to fix it (much easier when you can debug!) - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. It seems Facebook no longer sends the signed_request POST data with mobile devices which is why my login code wasn't working as before. Also, after a successful login I was redirecting to `apps.facebook.com/myappname` (in order to keep the app within the Facebook iframe), but this caused the login process to loop on mobile devices.

My fix was to change the mobile web URL in the app settings to include a query string param so I can differentiate between post-login requests from mobile/desktop. For normal requests I redirect to apps.facebook.com/myappname. For mobile ones I don't. So mobile devices no longer sit within the Facebook iframe but this is actually better in a way.